# use jquery variable dynamically inside php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this jquery script. It´s a range slider which creates values between 1 and 25.

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 25,
    value: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
   });
   $( "#amount" ).val( $("#slider-range-max").slider("value") );
 });
</script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; 
 font-weight:bold;">

 <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
```

Now I need the current value (which is chosen at the moment) **dynamically** inside of the following php script. The link inside of the php script needs to change dynamically when the slider values gets changed.

**Part of the php code**

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('https://example.de/?id=DYNAMIC SLIDER VALUE');
.....

 ?>
```

How is this possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you go from your HTML towards the PHP file? Is there a form? Perhaps you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50320354/edit) your question and explain to us what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The html is just the output of the slider. Now I need the chosen value of the slider (1-25)  dynamically in my php script.

Comment: Ye that much we understood. But what are you trying to achieve? For example _"User visits website. User sets slider. User clicks button and is forwarded to a new page where the contents of the file are displayed"_. Explain us your project.

Comment: If the user uses the slider (1-25) the value needs to get in the url of my php script. Then I will echo different numbers out of a php array. The different url values leads to different arrays.

Comment: I'm not asking what you're going to do _after_ the slider value is in your PHP script. I'm asking you how you get there? You're jumping a bridge here. It's like you're going from A to B and from B directly to D. Where is step C? Where is the content loaded _after_ the user changes the slider? Is it supposed to display on the same website when the user changes the slide? Does the user go to a new page after changing the slider? You're skipping the connection between the HTML page with the slider and your PHP file. Without that connection, we can't properly give you an answer.

Comment: The change happens on the same site. So the users see the new output after they re changing the slider (dynamically). The site shouldn´t reload.

Comment: Thank you! Now we're getting somewhere. Is the content supposed to load into `<input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">` in your html?

Comment: Nope the content should appear seperately in a php echo. It has nothing to do with the slider. For that I need the values of the sliders dynamically  as a php variable.

Comment: Alright, anwered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic behavior in the browser does not directly create a dynamic result on your server. In order to do that you must send the value of the slider to the server. The mechanism for doing that is AJAX. So in your event handler for the slider you can send the current value to the server like this:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
  fetch("/url/to/your/php/script.php", {
    body: JSON.stringify({value: ui.value}), 
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST'
  });
}
```

At that point, your PHP script will need to use the value to modify the URL to replace `DYNAMIC SLIDER VALUE` with the value from the slider.

Please note that you should take precautions when doing this as you will thrash your server. You should throttle the requests to avoid this. You can investigate Underscore's throttle method.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question yet. You don't know if OP is trying to load content into the current document, is initiating a file download or simply browsing towards a new page. There's no way to give a correct answer. You can only guess.

Comment: I very directly answered this: **_Now I need the current value (which is chosen at the moment) dynamically inside of the following php script. The link inside of the php script needs to change dynamically when the slider values gets changed._** along with this: **_How is this possible?_**

Comment: Right. And what if the user is actually trying to litterly change the source code of the PHP file with the slider? As I said: You lack enough information.

Comment: Hence my first statement that addresses that directly: _Dynamic behavior in the browser does not directly create a dynamic result on your server._

Answer (score 0):

Alright. To get content from PHP into your HTML webpage without reloading, you'll need Ajax. Ajax allowes you to send data (like your slider value) towards your PHP file and retrieve the result back into a Javascript variable. After that, you can simply use that variable to put the content anywhere you want on your HTML webpage.

First the Javascript:

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
        range: "max",
        min: 1,
        max: 25,
        value: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            /* Here we send the slider value towards PHP */
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "your_php_file.php",
                data: { sliderVal: ui.value }
            })
            /* Here we receive the data back */
            .done(function(data) {
                /* Here you can do whatever you want with the data */
                $("#content").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $("#slider-range-max").slider("value") );
});
</script>
```

You'll have to change `your_php_file.php` into your PHP file above. Now lets say for example you have the following div element in your HTML code:

```
<div id='content'></div>
```

Then whatever is returned by your PHP file will load inside this div because we're passing it above in Javascript with: `$("#content").html(data);`

Next we'll have to look at the PHP file:

```
<?php

$str = file_get_contents('https://example.de/?id='. $_POST['sliderVal']);

echo $str;

?>
```

If you look back at the Javascript code, you'll see that we made a POST `method: "POST"` request to your PHP file with the variable `sliderVal` containing the slider value: `data: { sliderVal: ui.value }`. So all we have to do is retrieve that value inside your PHP file with `$_POST['sliderVal']`. Now it will dynamicly load the contents of the file you're requesting into the `$str` variable. All that's left to do is return that towards your Javascript with a simple `echo`.